# error when emulate ionic 2 app on android studio

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

On my **ionic 2** application, I would like to emaulte the application on **android studio**.

When I run this command on my terminal `ionic emulate -l -s android` I have this error:

> Error: Cannot find module './version'

This is the output on my terminal:

```
watch failed: watcher error: 

/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/src/assets/**/*,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/src/index.html,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/src/manifest.json,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/src/service-worker.js,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js,/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js:

Error: watch 
/home/user/Workspace/ionic-app/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts ENOSPC 
dev server running: http://192.168.0.149:8101/ 

Error: Cannot find module './version'
```

I don't understand where am I wrong. Why this error occured and what is this `./version` module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. During my project developpement, there was an update of android studio (sdk manager, sdk tools, gradle ... etc).

I have to delete the folder `ionic-app/platforms/android`, then re-build the application through android studio by importing the ionic application with gradle.